# How to join feathersjs jwt with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, feathersjs, feathers-authentication

I try to do login to my application using local users kept in mongodb. My application works on Node.js using feathersjs. After run the app I receive an error like below:

```
Error: You must provide a 'header' in your authentication configuration or pass one explicitly
```

This is my config file:

```
{
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 3030,
  "public": "../public/",
  "paginate": {
    "default": 10,
    "max": 50
  },
  "authentication": {
    "secret": "My secret key",
    "strategies": [
      "jwt",
      "local"
    ],
    "path": "/authentication",
    "service": "authentication",
    "jwt": {
      "header": {
        "type": "access"
      },
      "audience": "https://yourdomain.com",
      "subject": "anonymous",
      "issuer": "feathers",
      "algorithm": "HS256",
      "expiresIn": "1d"
    },
    "local": {
      "entity": "user",
      "usernameField": "email",
      "passwordField": "password"
    }
  },
  "mongodb": "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb"
}
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in a recent version of `feathers-cli` which has been fixed in `v2.3.7` so make sure `feathers --version` show that version. In an existing application you can fix the error message with by changing `src/app.js` from

```
app.configure(jwt(config.jwt));
app.configure(local(config.local));
```

To

```
app.configure(jwt());
app.configure(local());
```

Comment: I changed `"jwt": { "header": { "type": "access" },` on `"header": "Authorization",` and my app is running but I don't know if it is a good solution. Yesterday I reinstalled npm and feathers-cli but my version is 2.3.6 How can I install newest version of feathers-cli?

Comment: I use feathers-authentication, I don't have any lines like above in my project.

Comment: OK, I have now 2.3.7 version. Thanks!